# Create dynamic PDF for users and send with email in nodes

Tags: node.js, email, pdf, sendgrid, mailgun

I have list of users. When I click submit detail then
I want to create PDF file dynamically according to users detail and send with email to all users in nodejs.

Comment: take a look at pdfmake for server/client side generation

Comment: Mailgun is in charge of sending the email and content only. You need to find a way to create that PDF and attached it to the mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really something that MailGun is designed to handle. You're responsible for creating the content and they're responsible for sending the content.

If you need to create a PDF dynamically, I'd recommend using Node or PHP to create your content as HTML/CSS and then using a library like [html2pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2pdf.js/v/0.9.0) or a service like [PDFShift](https://www.pdfshift.io) to render your output in PDF form.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a PDF dynamically i would suggest you to use **pdf-creator-node**
and for sending mails i would suggest you to use **nodemailer**
 you can use this [repo](https://github.com/sainithink/Dynamic-pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Docamatic](https://docamatic.com). It allows you to to create and send a PDF in a single API request.

```
{
    "source": "https://my-site.com/invoice.html",
    "email": {
        "to": "accounts@my-customer.com",
        "subject": "July Invoice"
    }
}
```